# Is there any way to match a string with only one character into character 'X' in sed?

Tags: sed, regex-group

I want to match all strings that have only one single character (including having with `+` or `-`) to turn into `X` but I get this output instead whenever I run it:

```
Xone     X
Xtwo     X
Xthree   X
```

Here's the file that I'm supposed to run with:

```
Cone      A-
Ctwo      D
Cthree    C+
```

Here's the code I've been working on:

code.sed

```
#!/bin/sed
s/[A-D][+-]/X/
s/[A-D]/X/
```

Desired output:

```
Cone      X
Ctwo      X
Cthree    X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a GNU `sed`, you can use

```sh
 sed -E 's/\b[[:upper:]]\b[+-]?/X/g'
```

*Details*:

- `-E` enables POSIX ERE syntax
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[[:upper:]]` - an uppercase letter
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[+-]?` - an optional `+` or `-`.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/oeCIwZ):

```sh
s='Cone      A-
Ctwo      D
Cthree    C+'
sed -E 's/\b[[:upper:]]\b[+-]?/X/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
Cone      X
Ctwo      X
Cthree    X
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '{gsub(/\<[A-Z]\>[-+]?/,"X")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply globally substituting capital letter(placing word boundary before it) followed by optional + or - with X in current line.